# Log problem, $u$ substitution the only way?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Okay so basically I want to know if you can solve this log equation without the use of u substitution:

$${\log_4{\log_3{x}}} = 1$$

I believe that u substitution is the only way to solve this problem, but please prove me wrong if theres another way to do so.

Comment: Take $4$ to the power of each side. Then do the same thing for $3$...

Answer (score 7):

Since I do not know what $u$-substitution means, it will have to be done another way. To say that $\log_4$ of something is $1$ means that the something is $4^1$. So $\log_3 x=4$. And this means that $x=3^4$.

Answer (score 0):

There is basic identity of log is:   $\log_ab=n\implies a^n=b $

so in your question : $\log_4\log_3x=1\,$, we put $\log_3x=u$

$$\log_4u=1\implies u=4^1\implies u=4\implies\log_3x=4\implies x=3^4\implies x=81$$